# python import of local module failing when run as systemd/systemctl service

Tags: python, python-import, systemd

I have a python application that I'm tring to run as a system service. The application runs fine when I run it manually. When I run it as a service it fails to find a local module that was installed with `pip install -e my_module`.

The main of the application has the following code:

```
print(sys.argv)
import pip
installed_packages = pip.get_installed_distributions()
installed_packages_list = sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version) for i in installed_packages])
print(installed_packages_list)
print('doing tox')
import tox
print('doing my_mod')
import my_mod
print(my_mod.__file__)
from my_mod.auth.http_auth_provider import HTTPAuthProvider
```

When I run it manually I get (note that my-mod is include on second line in 'installed packages'):

```
['/usr/bin/pv_api']
['aiohttp==0.19.0', 'chardet==2.3.0', 'jsonschema==2.5.1', 'pip==7.0.0', 'pluggy==0.3.1', 'pv-api==0.0.0', 'py==1.4.31', 'pycrypto==2.6.1', 'pymongo==3.1.1', 'pyyaml==3.11', 'setuptools==19.6.2', 'six==1.10.0', 'tox==2.3.1', 'virtualenv==14.0.6', 'my-mod==0.1.0', 'webauthsession==1.1.1']
doing tox
doing my_mod
/root/my_module/my_mod/__init__.py
```

When run through the service the logs look like this (note that my-mod is NOT included on second line in 'installed packages')::

```
2016-02-26_00:39:01.90403 ['/usr/bin/pv_api']
2016-02-26_00:39:01.90406 ['aiohttp==0.19.0', 'chardet==2.3.0', 'jsonschema==2.5.1', 'pip==7.0.0', 'pluggy==0.3.1', 'pv-api==0.0.0', 'py==1.4.31', 'pycrypto==2.6.1', 'pymongo==3.1.1', 'pyyaml==3.11', 'setuptools==19.6.2', 'six==1.10.0', 'tox==2.3.1', 'virtualenv==14.0.6', 'webauthsession==1.1.1']
2016-02-26_00:39:01.90407 doing tox
2016-02-26_00:39:01.90407 doing my_mod
2016-02-26_00:39:01.90642 Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-02-26_00:39:01.90642   File "/usr/bin/pv_api", line 9, in <module>
2016-02-26_00:39:01.90642     load_entry_point('pv-api==0.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'pv_api')()
2016-02-26_00:39:01.90643   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 547, in load_entry_point
2016-02-26_00:39:01.90643     return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
2016-02-26_00:39:01.90643   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2719, in load_entry_point
2016-02-26_00:39:01.90643     return ep.load()
2016-02-26_00:39:01.90643   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2379, in load
2016-02-26_00:39:01.90643     return self.resolve()
2016-02-26_00:39:01.90643   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2385, in resolve
2016-02-26_00:39:01.90644     module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
2016-02-26_00:39:01.90644   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pv/api/main.py", line 33, in <module>
2016-02-26_00:39:01.90644     import my_mod
2016-02-26_00:39:01.90644 ImportError: No module named 'my_mod'
```

This might also be useful information:

```
[root@7bb8a6866a85 etc]# ls -la /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/my-mod.egg-link 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 37 Feb 26 00:20 /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/my-mod.egg-link
[root@7bb8a6866a85 etc]# cat /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/my-mod.egg-link 
/root/my_module
```

***Edit:***

As you can see from the output of 'installed_packages' all other packages that are installed via requirements.txt are found correctly. Just this one library that I have source code for locally is not found when I run as service. (It is found when I run from the command line or when I run `import my_mod` from the python3 interpreter.

Answer (score 69):

I had a very similar issue converting an upstart `heartbeat.conf` to a systemd `heartbeat.service`, except with the `requests` module. The solution was to specify in the new .service what user to run it as:

```
[Unit]
Description=web server monitor

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/<user>/
User=<user>
ExecStart=/home/<user>/heartbeat.py
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Without the `User=<user>`, I was getting in the journalctl:

```
systemd[1]: Started web server monitor.
heartbeat.py[26298]: Traceback (most recent call last):
heartbeat.py[26298]:   File "/home/<user>/heartbeat.py", line 2, in <
heartbeat.py[26298]:     import requests
heartbeat.py[26298]: ImportError: No module named requests
systemd[1]: heartbeat.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: heartbeat.service: Unit entered failed state.
```

Comment: Note that it is `User=<user>`. Value depends on the username!

Comment: @kuga Excellent point. I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 7):

Add the python site packages environment variable to the systemctl *. Service file

```
[Unit]
Description=web server monitor

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/
User=user
ExecStart=/home/user/heartbeat.py
Restart=always
Environment="PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/nvidia/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: That worked for me, once I set up the Environment Path everything worked just fine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

If you do want to run the service as root, you have to install the module with sudo: `sudo pip install my_module`.

Answer (score 3):

First try the following in python prompt.

```
$ python
>>> import my_mod
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named my_mod
>>>
```

**Fix 1**

If you are getting the above sort of output then the cause may be because of permission issue. Grant permission for site-packages using the following.

```
sudo chmod -R go+rX /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

**Fix 2**

Try exporting the PYTHONPATH as below:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/usr/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages"
```

**Fix 3**

Check if you have multiple version of python running in same machine.

If so, check whether you have proper interpreter is included at the beginning of the code like `#!/usr/bin/python`

Comment: This came quite close to highlighting the real problem. The problem was that the service was being run as a user that didn't have read permissions on the folder from which my module was installed.

Answer (score 1):

1) Install the `supervisor` package ([more verbose instructions here](http://supervisord.org/installing.html)):

```
sudo apt-get install supervisor
```

2) Create a config file for your daemon at `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/my_mod.conf`:

```
[program:my_mod]
directory=/path/to/project/root
environment=ENV_VARIABLE=example,OTHER_ENV_VARIABLE=example2
command=python my_mod.py
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

3) Restart `supervisor` to load your new `.conf`

```
supervisorctl update
supervisorctl restart my_mod
```

Comment: The service is already installed. The problem is that the environment python picks up does not contain this one library. All other libraries that are install via the requirements file are found correctly.

Comment: How about adding this line `sys.path.append("/root/my_module/my_mod")` before importing my_mod?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I figured `pip install` must be user specific.
So I switched to root and then installed the packages. It worked after that.

However, I think specifying `User=myUser` in the service file would be a more proper way, however, I wanted it to run with root permissions and I wasn't sure it will when I specify the user.

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 1):

Since your python script is executing with `python3.4`, your problem is very likely the use of `pip` instead of `pip3` (or possibly `sudo -H pip3`).

But since you also ask specifically about using python modules from a *systemd* service, I would recommend using `apt` with `sudo` if at all possible, instead of messing with *pip* (which is notorious for introducing problems with file permissions):

```
sudo apt install python3-my_module
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm also getting import error but mine was not a local import. My package was not imported correctly. See service failure logs*

```
Feb 11 06:41:52 pl-dev-demo-1 python3[1675804]:     from foo import test
Feb 11 06:41:52 pl-dev-demo-1 python3[1675804]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'
Feb 11 06:41:52 pl-dev-demo-1 systemd[1]: xyzxyz.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

I wasted a lot of time to figure out then I tried this approach  which worked perfectly.

In module I set the path of my code :

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path_of_my_code_parent_package')

from foo import test
```

Read this doc :

[Setting PYTHONPATH more permanently](https://bic-berkeley.github.io/psych-214-fall-2016/using_pythonpath.html#setting-pythonpath-more-permanently)